# Relationship between limit and total variation

Tags: limits, total-variation

Consider a twice continuously differentiable and bounded function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ has the following property: in any neighborhood of $\infty$, there are an infinite number of intervals for which the total variation of $f$ is at least $C>0$. I am trying to figure out whether this implies that $f$ does not converge as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Is this a fixed $C$ or does the property hold true for all $C>0$?

Comment: It is for a fixed C; doesn't necessarily hold for all C>0

Comment: As far as I can tell, $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ satisfies the hypotheses, yet $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$.